# Nohup background process with lots of output

Tags: linux, nohup

I have an app the runs in the background via nohup, and it can optionally output debugging information. When I nohup it in debug mode, it runs for only about 12 hours before it dies. The debugging info comprises about 3 or 4 lines per second. Auditd is logging a signal 11. The app runs for at least 24 hours interactively with no problem.

Obviously, I won't run it in debug mode in production.

So I'm curious what is causing it to stop.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a segfault -- should generate a core dump.  Pump that through gdb, find out where it died.  The logging may be a red herring.  (Or: are you running out of disk space?)

Comment: I suspect I ran out of disk space, probably filling up nohup.out.